# Rhino mocks record\play model artefacts

Tags: .net, mocking, rhino

a have some artefacts when using Rhino Mocks

```
var mocks = new MockRepository();

INotifyMessageSender messageSenderMock; 

NotificationAgent notificationAgent = null;

var machineID = Guid.NewGuid();
messageSenderMock = mocks.DynamicMock<INotifyMessageSender>();                            
notificationAgent = new NotificationAgent(machineID, messageSenderMock);//in constructor                                 

//notification agent subscribes on messageSenderMock event MessageReceived
using (mocks.Record())
{           
    messageSenderMock.SendRegisterNodeMessage(machineID);          
}
notificationAgent.Start(); // this method should call messageSenderMock.SendRegisterNodeMestod
                             // and it calls this mesthod. i checked in debug mode
messageSenderMock.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing Rhino mock syntaxes. I would use the new AAA syntax. It's much easier.

```
INotifyMessageSender messageSenderMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<INotifyMessageSender>();

NotificationAgent notificationAgent = new NotificationAgent(Guid.NewGuid(), messageSenderMock);

notificationAgent.Start();

messageSenderMock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.SendRegisterNodeMessage(machineID));
```